# How to write contents of a dictionary in a messagebox?

Tags: c#, dictionary, messagebox

I'm working in Visual Studio C# and I have a "string-string" Dictionary variable with a few records, for example:

```
{Apartment1},{Free}

{Apartment2},{Taken}
```

etc...

How can I write this inside a messagebox so that it shows something like:

```
Apartment1 - Free

Apartment2 - Taken
```

etc...

It is important that each record is inside a new line in a message box.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Presumably you know how to access each item in your dictionary? And you know how to concatenate strings? What is stopping you?

Answer (score 5):

You could loop though each item in the dictionary and build a string, like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}{2}", item.Key, item.Value, Environment.NewLine);
}

string result = sb.ToString().TrimEnd();//when converting to string we also want to trim the redundant new line at the very end
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by means of a simple enumeration:

```
  // Your dictionary
  Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"Apartment1", "Free"},
    {"Apartment2", "Taken"}
  };

  // Message Creating 
  StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (var pair in dict) {
    if (S.Length > 0)
      S.AppendLine();

    S.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
  }

  // Showing the message
  MessageBox.Show(S.ToString());
```

Comment: +1 for not ending with a redundant new line... may have to add that to my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}\n", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string forBox = "";
foreach (var v in dictionary)            
    forBox += v.Key + " - " + v.Value + "\r\n";
MessageBox.Show(forBox);
```

OR:

```
string forBox = "";
foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
    forBox += key + " - " + dictionary[key] + "\r\n";
MessageBox.Show(forBox);
```

OR: (`using System.Linq;`)

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\r\n", dictionary.Select(pair => String.Join(" - ", pair.Key, pair.Value))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that with following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1} \\r\\n", item.Key, item.Value);
}

string result = sb.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(result);
```